Why levels which are not there in data, are mapped with alpha in ggplot2?
I am observing a strange behaviour.  Mapping cyl variables (from mtcars data) is producing the chart with 5 different levels of alpha despite the fact that only three levels are available there?
Is that a bug?  Or I am missing something?
library(tidyverse)
count(mtcars, cyl)
#>   cyl  n
#> 1   4 11
#> 2   6  7
#> 3   8 14

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(alpha = cyl), size = 4)


Created on 2024-08-24 with reprex v2.1.1

The reason is that cyl is a continuous variable and by default the number of breaks for a continuous scale is set using scales::breaks_extended (not 100% sure that this applies to all cases, though (: ) which also by default will return approx. n=5 breaks.
library(ggplot2)

scales::breaks_extended()(mtcars$cyl)
#> [1] 4 5 6 7 8

The simple approach to fix that would be to convert to a factor:
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(alpha = factor(cyl)), size = 4)
#> Warning: Using alpha for a discrete variable is not advised.


Or set the breaks explicitly via the scale:
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(alpha = cyl), size = 4) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(breaks = sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)))



Thanks I agree on that part using scale, but regarding the suggestion of using discrete variable, ggplot2 itself warns against it

Yeah. Not recommend. And the reason I added the second option. (: But this is more an advise from a data viz point of view. And we will get the same warning for aesthetics like size or linewidth.

@AnilGoyal:  As Stefan says, that advice is about visualization, not about programming.  They think that transparency is a bad marker for a class.  One reason for this is that two overlapping markers will appear to have a larger alpha value.  You can see this in the clump of values with the weight just less than 3.5, where two 6 cylinder markers overlap, and the common region is nearly as dark as the 8 cylinder markers.  If the overlap was greater, you might mistake two 6 cylinders for a single 8 cylinder.

@user2554330 very well explained.  Thanks
